# Is it possible to edit a pre-existing .class file from within my program?

Tags: java, python, class, jar, minecraft

This may seem like an odd thing to ask, but it'd take me forever to explain why I need it...

What I need is a way to edit a pre-existing Java .class file within its JAR file, with either a command prompt, or within my Python program. I need it to happen automatically, once the user pushes a button.

I have absolutely no clue how to do this, or if it's possible.

Comment: *"it'd take me forever to explain why I need it"*  That in itself should be listed as a 'bad design smell'.

Comment: @ Andrew It's because I'm making a utility for minecraft that allows you to build structures outside of the game, and import them into it, which requires me to either write the user-created code to a java file and then compile it, and put it into the minecraft.jar, which after two days of trying to figure this out, I've realized is completely impossible, because minecraft's class files have different names in the jar than what you use to call them in the code, so it can't access any of the class files it depends on. So, I need another way to import it into the game.

Comment: *"I'm making a utility for minecraft that allows you to build structures outside of the game, and import them into it"* — do you want to edit the map data for a particular world? Because that isn't stored inside a Java class file, and is *much* easier to edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A jar file is a zip package, you need only to extract the file, edit the content and put it back. The harder part is how to edit the .class file. [The java .class file is a binary format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) , there're [several libraries may help you](http://java-source.net/open-source/bytecode-libraries).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this. Now how you gonna do it depends upon what you want to do. For your cross-cutting issues look at [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/). Using AspectJ you can add your custom code even after the class is compiled.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with this approach, if the class has already been loaded by a JVM classloader, as it may not actually reread the .class file again until the application has been rerun.

I know that there exists the [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/) but I've not used it, so I dont know if it can be used a) from python, or b) during runtime.

EDIT: Actually, Jeffrey's list is better as it provides a much more comprehensive list of Byte Code manipulators.

Comment: The class file won't actually be changed while the java program is running, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Ok, in that case you should be fine (well, as fine as you can be with editing binary class files) with something on Jeffreys list. :)

Comment: Ah, I see, you are basically trying to make an application the edits the class files for a different application?

Comment: @D3_JMultiply Yes, pretty much.

Comment: interesting, I've not really seen too many people do it, but yeah, it's completely possible, either you use the binary libraries supplied by the other answers, or you could even use jad retro and such, extract, decompile from .class to .java, edit the coding, and recompile from .java to .class and inject. So there are quite a few way to do it

Comment: If you're feeling brave, you can even edit them directly in a hex editor.